# jquery fancybox shows only first line of ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I am using jquery fancybox 3.5.7. When I load ajax content like below it returns several lines with links. The problem is the popup only shows the first line. Why? The link to get the data:

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="/code/lenker.php?q=Abies%20alba" href="javascript:;" title="Flower" class="ajax">Click for a lightbox </a>
```

The returned data (XHR response in Chrome inspector)

```
<div><a class="external" href="http://databank.artsdatabanken.no/FremmedArt2012/N63753" data-featherlight="ajax">fremmedartsvurdering 2012 for edelgran</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="http://eol.org/pages/1033070" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran hos Encyclopedia of Life</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="http://linnaeus.nrm.se/flora/barr/pina/abies/abiealb.html" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran i Virtuella floran, Sverige</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="https://artsdatabanken.no/Fab2018/N/152" data-featherlight="ajax">Fremmedartsvurdering 2018 for edelgran</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="https://artsdatabanken.no/Taxon/Abies%20alba/103793" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran hos Artsdatabanken</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="https://artskart.artsdatabanken.no/app/#map/286667,6576955/7/background/NiB/filter/%7B%22TaxonIds%22%3A%5B129966%5D%2C%22AreaIds%22%3A%5B2595%5D%2C%22Months%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22TaxonGroupIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22IncludeSubTaxonIds%22%3Atrue%2C%22Categories%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22BasisOfRecords%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Behaviors%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22InstitutionIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22CollectionIds%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22CatalogNumbers%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Img%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Found%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22NotRecovered%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Valid%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22UnsureId%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Spontan%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Cons%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22CenterPoints%22%3Afalse%2C%22Geometry%22%3A%22%22%2C%22BoundingBox%22%3A%22%22%2C%22LocationId%22%3A0%2C%22Style%22%3A1%2C%22YearFrom%22%3A0%2C%22YearTo%22%3A0%2C%22CoordinatePrecisionFrom%22%3A0%2C%22CoordinatePrecisionTo%22%3A0%7D " data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran på Artskart i Østfold</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/edelgran" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran på Wikipedia</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="https://snl.no/edelgran" data-featherlight="ajax">edelgran i Store norske leksikon</a></div>
<div><a class="external" href="https://www.gbif.org/species/2685484" data-featherlight="ajax">GBIF Verdensutbredelse edelgran</a></div>
```

The popup only shows this:

```
<a class="external" href="http://databank.artsdatabanken.no/FremmedArt2012/N63753" data-featherlight="ajax">fremmedartsvurdering 2012 for edelgran</a>
```

Always shows only the first line. If I use ajax to a page with the links hardcoded it shows all the links. So something happens when the code is generated. Any reason why it should not show all the html?

Comment: Wow Janis, I knew it was something simple! Not that your answer is simple but I have worked with jQuery for 10 years and never had to do exactly this :-) Thanks so much for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that ajax response should return one element that would be treated as "main content", therefore you should simply wrap all your content inside some `<div` element.

Comment: Thanks, I still have another problem if you have any idea. I am using DataTables and one of the cells in the table is a link that opens a lightbox with the list of links. If I have a static link outside the table with the same code, it works fine and the popup contains all the html. But if I click on the link in DataTables the lightbox is emtpy. No content! I can see in XHR traffic that I still get the correct html. Any idea why nothing shows in the popup? I have included fancybox.js at the very bottom of the document. Since the links open a lightbox the script should work?

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Janis works fine. Remember to add an outer  around all elements.
I also had a problem where clicking on the links generated in my DataTable would just show a blank fancybox popup. I solved this by creating a hidden DIV and doing an ajax call, filling the the **div** with the data and then calling fancybox() on the div. My div is `<div id="lenker" style="display:none"></div>`. The link created in DataTables is like this:

```
<a rel="Hesperis matronalis" href="#" class="show_link" title="Show links for Hesperis matronalis"><i class="fas fa-link fa-lg"></i></a>
```

Then when I click the link the data is fetched, written to the div, and called a fancybox popup.

```
  $("#example tbody").on('click','.show_link', function(e) {
      var nid = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.get("/code/lenker.php", {q: nid},
        function(data){
        $("#lenker").html(data);
    $.fancybox.open( $('#lenker'));
    extlink();
    });
   });
```